# Where are time zone zic source files managed?

Tags: timezone

There are numerous errors in the historical transitions in /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Asuncion tz file.
Transitions are incorrectly computed from around 2006 forward through 2038 as happening in second Sunday in March and first Sunday in November.
The posix rule in the file is: "<-04>4<-03>,M10.1.0/0,M3.4.0/0", which specifies first Sunday in October and 4th Sunday in March. I've confirmed this with multiple independent web sites. I suspect the zic source file is wrong. Where are these managed for Debian/Ubuntu? Happy to go fix the ones I run into.
This is the first tz file with errors -- I suspect I'll find more...

Comment: Please file a bug report against the `tzdata` package: `ubuntu-bug tzdata`

Comment: https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html#changes

Answer (score 0):

I built the IANA files from their git repository, and the default tz compile apparently does not use the included Posix rule to extend transitions past the last rule change up to year 2038 as do all files in the Ubuntu/Debian release. The IANA-built files do not have the problem.

As for the 598 timezone names in /usr/share/zoneinfo, only these have problems with the extrapolated transitions not matching the included posix rule:

America/Asuncion, America/Godthab, America/Miquelon, America/Nuuk, America/Santiago, America/Scoresbysund, Antarctica/Troll, Atlantic/Azores, Australia/LHI, Australia/Lord_Howe, Chile/Continental, Chile/EasterIsland, NZ-CHAT, Pacific/Chatham, Pacific/Easter, Pacific/Norfolk

I'll file the bug report.